# How can I execute two commands in terminal using Python's subprocess module?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, popen

How can I use the subprocess module (i.e. `call`, `check_call` and `Popen`) to run more than one command?

For instance, lets say I wanted to execute the `ls` command twice in quick sucession, the following syntax does not work

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['ls', 'ls'])
```

returns:

```
CalledProcessError: Command '['ls', 'ls']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

Comment: Does `for _ in range(2): subprocess.Popen('ls')` not work for your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `&&` or `;`:

```
$ ls && ls
file.txt file2.txt
file.txt file2.txt

$ ls; ls
file.txt file2.txt
file.txt file2.txt
```

The difference is that in case of `&&` the second command will be executed only if the first one was successful (try `false && ls`) unlike the `;` in which case the command will be executed independently from the first execution.

So, Python code will be:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["ls; ls"], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just execute the command twice.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['ls'])
subprocess.check_call(['ls'])
```

That should be quick enough.

**Edit**

If you want to execute two commands in the same shell, write a shell script that executes them and run this script from Python.

Comment: I'm afraid my question is a simplification of a more complicated problem. I actually do need to execute two commands one after the other, in the same shell. Thanks for responding though.

Answer (score 1):

This following code would work. But wouldn't it be better to just execute the ls command twice?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["ls;ls"],shell=True)
```